# How to pass a value between factorys in Ionic?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, filesystems, factory

I need yours help.
I have two `.factory's` in `Services.js`
The first `.factory` works with a database, the second `.factory` with e-mail, files and so on. 
How to pass a value from first factory to second? How to select data from the first factory?

```
//first factory

angular.module('starter.services', ['ngCordova', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'])
.factory('NotesDataService', function ($cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform) {
var db, dbName = "CONTACTS_DB"

function useWebSql() {
  db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", "Contacts database", 200000)
  console.info('Using webSql')
}

function useSqlLite() {
  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: dbName, location : 1})
  console.info('Using SQLITE')
}

function initDatabase(){
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_CONTACTS (id integer primary key, nom, prenom, codePostale, ville, email, portable)')
    .then(function(res){

    }, onErrorQuery)
}

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if(window.cordova){
    useSqlLite()
  } else {
    useWebSql()
  }

  initDatabase()
})

function onErrorQuery(err){
  console.error(err)
}

return{
  getAll: function(callback){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM T_CONTACTS').then(function (results) {
        var data = []

        for (i = 0, max = results.rows.length; i < max; i++) {
          data.push(results.rows.item(i))
        }

        callback(data)
      }, onErrorQuery)
    })
  }})




//second factory, here I need to get data from first factory
//to create a text file with the data from the database
// and attach this file to the e-mail

.factory('ContactsService', function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaEmailComposer, $cordovaSQLite, $cordovaFile, NotesDataService) {



 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {


initCordovaEmailComposer();
  })



 function initCordovaEmailComposer() {
    $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function () {
      //is available
      alert('avaible');
    }, function () {
      //not available
      alert('not available');
    })
  }

  return {
    createEmail: function () {
      var email = {
        to: 'test@gmail.com',
        cc: 'test@gmail.com',
        bcc: 'test@gmail.com',
        attachments: [
          'file://cordova.file.externalDataDirectory/contacts.txt',
        ],
        subject: 'Cordova Icons',
        body: "Hello, mon ami",
        isHtml: true
      };


  $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
  });
},

debugMessage: function (data) {
  console.log('debug message', data);
},

createFile: function () {
  var fileContacts = document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    NotesDataService.getAll(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    return data
    })
    console.log('file contacts in console: ',fileContacts)
    var fileName = 'contacts.txt'
    var fileText = fileContacts
    var filePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
    //CHECK file
    $cordovaFile.checkFile(filePath, fileName).then(function (success) {
        alert("file exist")
      }, function (error) {
        alert("file not exist", filePath)

      //WRITE NEW FILE
      $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, fileName, fileText, true).then(function (success) {
          // success
        }, function (error) {
          // error
        });

          });
      })
    }, 
   }
  })
```

Thank you all for your advice and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject these factories into one another :

.factory('NotesDataService',['$cordovaSQLite','$ionicPlatform','ContactsService', function ($cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform,ContactsService) ....

.factory('ContactsService',['$ionicPlatform',.....,'NotesDataService', function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaEmailComposer, $cordovaSQLite, $cordovaFile, NotesDataService) {

Now you can use either factory variables and functions in other factory.

Comment: Thank you)
I need to change the template?
I have a error 

 `ionic.bundle.js:26799 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NotesDataServiceProvider <- NotesDataService <- ListCtrl`